# MySQL check for crashed table

Tags: mysql

I notice that when phpMyAdmin opens a DB it shows immediately if a table has crashed or not. It thus seems to me that phpMyAdmin is not running a `CHECK TABLE` or `ANALYZE TABLE`.

Does anybody know what it does to obtain this informaiton so quickly and efficiently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I bet that

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `db`;
```

is the thing you're looking for.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/gerrywastaken/phpmyadmin-GitHubed/blob/master/db_structure.php#L438) line. I think that if ENGINE is null (empty), it may be because table is crashed

Comment: There may be situations where this is helpful, but not in mine.  `SHOW TABLE STATUS` doesn't give any difference in status for the tables I have corrupted.

Comment: @mc0e, not only does it not show crashed all the time - a table isn't marked as crashed _until it's used_.  So getting the status on a table that hasn't been read/written to will yield nothing.  If you suffer an event that causes crashed tables, the best thing you can do is run a repair on all of them instead of waiting for them to tell you they are crashed.  **SO THIS ACCEPTED ANSWER IS WRONG**

Comment: The OP asked how phpMyAdmin got the table status so fast, so this answer is quite likely correct (though unsubstantiated, and expressed as a guess).  The answer could however be substantially improved with info from @Dev_Null 's comment

Answer (score 16):

```
show table status where comment like '%crash%';
```

Comment: I like this better than accepted answer, because it's not apparent in accepted answer that you can easily use LIKE within the context of a SHOW statement.  (Also, I prefer COMMENT != "".)

Answer (score 9):

The most efficient way I have found is to use the commandline `mysqlcheck` tool:

`mysqlcheck -u mydbuser -p mydbname`

This will access `mydbname` using user `mydbuser` and prompting for that user's password. It will then check each table in the specified database.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html

Note: this is not how phpMyAdmin does it, so this is not strictly an answer for the original question, but I'm putting this here because Google sends searches for `mysql show crashed tables` here.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a shell access, the `mysqlanalyze` utility could help.

```
mysqlanalyze dbname
```

[Official Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to check a table is

```
mysqlcheck DB TABLE
```

so to check table BAR in Database FOO

```
mysqlcheck FOO BAR
```